# Spring does not find bean

Tags: spring, applicationcontext, openapi-generator

I get the following error:

```
Field delegate in package.rest.api.MyApiController required a bean of type 'package.rest.api.MyApiDelegate' that could not be found.
```

I've tried to add annotation @ComponentScan("package.rest") to the main class, but it didn't help.

```
package package;
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(SpecificationConf.class)
//@ComponentScan("package.rest")
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
package package.rest.api;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(...)
public class MyApiController implements MyApi {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myService")
    private MyApiDelegate delegate;

}
```

```
package package.rest;

@Service("myService")
public class MyApiDelegateImpl implements MyApiDelegate {
...
}
```

```
package package.rest.api;

public interface MyApiDelegate {
...
}
```

Can that problem happen due to incorrect configuration of the Application context or an inappropriate maven profile? I've tried to move classes to the same package, but it also didn't help.

Comment: Try @ComponentScan("package.rest.*")

Comment: Are you deploying a WAR file instead of packaging your Spring Boot application in the default JAR file?

Comment: @JoãoDias I deploy a jar file, can it be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are building a JAR file and not a WAR file, please try dropping `SpringBootServletInitializer` from your main class as follows:

```java
package package;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(SpecificationConf.class)
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't solve the problem:(

Comment: Is the issue the same? What does `SpecificationConf` do? Can you add its code?

Comment: Seems like I solved the problem by adding WEB-INF folder and web.xml file in it. Thank you

Comment: That is definitely weird, but if it works. Add it as an answer and accept it so that others may benefit from it.